# Trim values of csv in nifi

Tags: regex, groovy, trim, apache-nifi

I'm processing csv file using nifi where I want to trim whitespaces before int values either using groovy script or replaceText processor. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **CsvReader/CSVSetWriter** controller services to read/write the data and

> Trim Fields   **true**

- Whether or not white space should be removed from the beginning and end of fields

  [image]

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/115311/convert-csv-to-json-avro-xml-using-convertrecord-p.html) link to how to configure/enable CsvReader/writer controller services.

(or)

You can use **QueryRecord processor** and add new query as a dynamic property to the processor as

```
select trim(field_name) from FLOWFILE
```

refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) link for more details regarding to Query Record processor.

Comment: It doesn't work when use CsvReader Trim Fields true, but I will try QueryRecord processor.